# Is it possible to connect Xcode with iPhone over internet for development?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new in iOS app development. Currently I work on a project which is use CoreBluetooth framework, thats why I can't test my app using xcode simulator. Also I don't have iPhone to test at this moment. So I want to test my app using my friend's iPhone. Is it possible to do this remotely? Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very difficult. Something similar I did sometime to test a specific device of a friend is to connect to his Mac using TeamViewer and basicaly using Xcode on his computer remotely, not ideal and only for very specific case, I strongly recommend to search for a used iPhone.